# Update-Database (EF Core 5) Failing (Code First)

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-5.0

I upgraded my environment to ASP.NET Core 5.01 and I'm having some difficulties updating the database using the code first approach.  The Add-Migration command works as expected and generates the correct migration source file.  However, when I try to run the Update-Database I'm getting errors. Here's the output of my PMC:

```
PM> add-migration Project
Build started...
Build succeeded.
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
PM> Update-Database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'SaberDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
PM>
```

When running the Update-Database -verbose, I get the following output:

```
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile
> C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal\SaberTooth.Data\bin\Debug\net5.0\SaberTooth.Model.deps.json
> --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\valere\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig
> C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal\SaberTooth.Data\bin\Debug\net5.0\SaberTooth.Model.runtimeconfig.json
> C:\Users\valere\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\5.0.1\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll
> database update --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly
> C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal\SaberTooth.Data\bin\Debug\net5.0\SaberTooth.Model.dll
> --startup-assembly C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal\SaberTooth.Data\bin\Debug\net5.0\SaberTooth.Model.dll
> --project-dir C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal\SaberTooth.Data\ --language C# --working-dir C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal --root-namespace SaberTooth.Model Using assembly 'SaberTooth.Model'. Using startup assembly 'SaberTooth.Model'. Using application base
> 'C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal\SaberTooth.Data\bin\Debug\net5.0'.
> Using working directory
> 'C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal\SaberTooth.Data'. Using root
> namespace 'SaberTooth.Model'. Using project directory
> 'C:\TFS_VSTUDIO\SaberToothPortal\SaberTooth.Data\'. Remaining
> arguments: . Finding DbContext classes... Finding
> IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations... Finding application
> service provider in assembly 'SaberTooth.Model'... Finding
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider... No static method
> 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'. No
> application service provider was found. Finding DbContext classes in
> the project... Found DbContext 'SaberDbContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to
> create an object of type 'SaberDbContext'. For the different patterns
> supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728  --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[SaberTooth.Model.SaberDbContext]'
> while attempting to activate 'SaberTooth.Model.SaberDbContext'.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type type)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1
> factory)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
> contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action)
```

The output suggests that there is no CreateHostBuilder in the Program.cs class yet it's clearly there:

```
namespace SaberTooth.Model
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

If I subsequently try to issue the Remove-Migration command, I get the same results:

```
PM> Remove-Migration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'SaberDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
PM>
```

I've looked up the suggested link in the error message but I don't see where I am doing something wrong.  I've also literally performed a half a dozen migrations without a problem (before upgrading) using exactly the same steps which are:

```
1.  Create the Model:  
2.  Create the Interface:
3.  Add a DBSet Declaration in the SaberDbContext.cs File
4.  Create the Repository
5.  Add a Scope to the Startup.cs File
6.  Run the add-migration command
7.  Run the update-database command
```

I'm fairly new to EF.  This is my very first attempt at using it for a project.  Any assistance would really be appreciated.  Am I doing something incorrectly now that I've upgrade to .Net Core 5.0.1?

Thanks

--- Val

Comment: By "`Add-Database` command" I guess you mean `Add-Migration`? And it ran successfully? If yes, please run `Update-Database -Verbose` and post the output. Hopefully it will give some clue what's going wrong (there could be some exception etc.)

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev, Add-Migration, correct.  I updated my post and also added the verbose output as you suggested.

Comment: Could you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new?labels=customer-reported&template=bug_report_efcore.md)? This looks like something we should investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work.  Here's what I did:

I updated the Configure Services method in my Startup class and changed the following entry:

```
services.AddDbContext<SaberDbContext>();
```

to:

```
    string _connectionString;
    string appSettings = String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/appsettings.json");
    var configurationSettings = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(appSettings).Build();
    _connectionString = configurationSettings["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

    services.AddDbContext<SaberDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString));
```

and that did the trick.  Not sure why this worked with .NET Core 3.x and it doesn't with 5.x. Like I said, I'm new to Entity Framework and Web Application Development (this is my first project) so I'm sure somewhere I'm not using the correct definitions.  For now it works though!

--- Val